# What is effected when I change the URL of a subsite?

Tags: url, sub-site

I have not come across the need to change an existing subsite yet until now.  I know how to change it, but what is effected once the URL has been changed?

I have existing workflows, photos that are linked with the old URL, lists, and document libraries.  Will these be effected by the change?  Will they become broken links?

I am only looking to change the subsite URL not the root site URL.

Comment: SharePoint take's care of updating the most of it like the quick launch, navigation, image urls, library urls and such. If you are using hardcoded links somewhere, like in a workflow or some custom code, you will need to update those.

Comment: Thanks. I don't want to open a can of worms and be working most of the day to find and correct them.

Comment: Haha, never heard that expression before, good one. If you would need to change it someday and you know that there is lot's of custom code in the site you can use Powershell to find all webparts that might contain custom code (Content editor webpart/script editor webpart) or even URL's. :)

Comment: And for the sake of it, before a change you can just copy the subsite to a test environment and change the URL there and take a tour through the site to see if anything broke.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  There isn't too much custom code, more in the workflows with HTML tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go into Title, description, and navigation in the Site Settings of your subsite and change your site from something like `http://sp/sites/team1/functionalarea` to `http://sp/sites/team1/funcarea`, these are some of the things you can expect.

- Most internal things SharePoint controls will be updated as you'd expect
- Rich content areas may now have broken links/images
- Bookmarked content by users will now lead to 404 errors because the URLs have changed
- The recent tab in Office applications will lead to 404 errors when users try to access the files because the URLs have changed
- Custom workflows could now have links pointing to wrong URLs

It can be really jarring to your end users, be sure to communicate the underlying URL is changing and note that any bookmarked content or links in Office Applications need updated.

Comment: Thanks, this was a request the team made nothing I would willingly do to them haha.  Again thanks and thanks to @christoffer for all the quick assistance.